# Explanation button in tablesorter

Tags: html, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter and there are a few columns on in my table where I need to put a question mark button next to it to give a detailed explanation of the column title. This is generally not too difficult to implement, but the issue arrises when you click on the question mark button it selects that columns and sorts it with table sorter. How can I change my code so that clicking on the question mark button doesn't enable to sort on the column?

Here is an example of my one of my column headers:

```
    <th data-field="balance" data-footer="-">Column Title<div class="info-icon">
      <div class="tooltip-container">
        <div class="tooltip-tail top"></div>
          <div class="tooltip top clearfix">
            Description of what the column does
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </th>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you wanted the tooltips to work, but you could use the `onRenderHeader` function to bind to the icon to toggle the tooltip container ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1036/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({

    // customize header HTML
    onRenderHeader: function (index) {
        $(this).find('.info-icon').click(function () {
            $(this).find('.tooltip-container').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    }

});
```